# How to split an arraylist elements that returning from a webservices?

Tags: android, web-services, split

#### Here is my code. I am convertted webservices object to an arraylist and I wrote in logcat. I want to split every elements of arraylist.

```
httpTransport.call(degiskenler.SOAP_ACTION4, envelope);    

                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    int count = result.getPropertyCount();
                    ArrayList<String> simplifiedList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        simplifiedList.add(result.getPropertyAsString(i));
                    }

                    for (String itm : simplifiedList) {
                    String[] itm1=itm.split(";");
                          System.out.println("The itm contains the following elements: "
                                + itm);
                          System.out.println("The itm1 contains the following elements: "
                                    + itm1);
                    }

                    System.out.println("The arraylist contains the following elements: "
                                            + simplifiedList);
```

#### here is my logcat and I want to get every "4-223.443-221.2343" element in string format. I am trying split in itm1 but it is not worked.

```
05-19 06:37:17.956: I/System.out(1423): The itm contains the following elements: anyType{anyType=1-223.443-221.2343; anyType=4-223.443-221.2343; anyType=5-223.443-221.2343; }
05-19 06:37:17.956: I/System.out(1423): The itm1 contains the following elements: [Ljava.lang.String;@b41f6ae0
05-19 06:37:17.966: I/System.out(1423): The arraylist contains the following elements: [anyType{anyType=1-223.443-221.2343; anyType=4-223.443-221.2343; anyType=5-223.443-221.2343; }]
```

#### And my webservice

```
<ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1-223.443-221.2343</anyType>
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">4-223.443-221.2343</anyType>
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">5-223.443-221.2343</anyType>
</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

Comment: Where do you want to split? The data is coming like `1-223.443-221.2343` from server?

Comment: My problem is get string elements of my webservice. Returning type is arraylist of from webservice. Data is coming [anyType{anyType=1-223.443-221.2343; anyType=4-223.443-221.2343; anyType=5-223.443-221.2343; }] but I want to get only  "1-223.443-221.2343" and "4-223.443-221.2343" and "5-223.443-221.2343"

Comment: Does it have `=` sign? Can you just post the exact output that is coming from server? Are you getting the details in JSON format?

Comment: all my servers output is above. my webservice in asp.net.

Comment: Change this ` System.out.println("The itm1 contains the following elements: "+ itm1)` to  `System.out.println("The itm1 contains the following elements: "+ itm1[0])`

Comment: my servers return an arraylist and I want to get every string elements.

Comment: thanks for answer #Aniruddha. its worked. this time itm1 return "The itm1 contains the following elements: anyType{anyType=1-223.443-221.2343" But I dont want words that "anytpe{anytype..." I am want only "1-223.443-221.2343" please help..